# 3 dots and a comma in NumPy array display

Tags: numpy

I was printing one list of values in Python, when I got this:

```
[ 0.00020885  0.00021386  0.0002141  ...,  0.0501399   0.12051606
  0.12359095]
```

What is the problem here? The list should have at least size 20. What happened to the elements shown as `...`?

Comment: please show us some more code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you are not printing a Python list, but a NumPy array.  NumPy output can be configured using [`numpy.set_printoptions()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions).

Data types matter.  If you wonder about the behaviour of some object, first check its type.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought there was some automatic conversion between Python lists and Numpy arrays.  So what value should I assign to the threshold paramater to be able to print everything?
`numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=None)`  A generic large values will do, but can I have set no threshold at all?

Comment: @RickyRobinson: You can set the threshold to `numpy.inf` if you really want to.  I suggest to set it to some reasonable upper limit, though.